# Subtract a mask from a string in Delphi 10.3

Tags: string, delphi, masking

I collect resource dll file names into `TStringList` by a given mask. It works fine to that point. After that I want to collect the language codes contained by the file names. Is there any `built-in` function or a well formed `regexp` to get the right string section depending on the mask?

**Example 1:**

Mask :  resources_%s.dll

One of the collected file names : resources_en.dll

Language code : en

**Example 2:**

Mask :  %s_resources.dll

One of the collected file names : eng_resources.dll

Language code : eng

**Example 3:**

Mask :  res-%s.dll

One of the collected file names : res-en.dll

Language code : en

Comment: Do the masks contain at most one (1) instance of `%s`?

Comment: @KenWhite It is not so trivial by code as you think at first sight. The regexp solution far from me because of the missing knowledge. But if it is trivial, just give a solution pls and I will accept it (if it works fine as general as I wish) I'd like to ignore to create own code. this is the reason to ask for a built-in functionality. As I realized this page about 'How can I solve this problem' and not 'How can you tease me best' :)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand The number of '%s' is always 1. The main and the optional sub language codes build a whole. (resources_en_us.dll => en_us)

Comment: This is not a matter of teasing. It's a matter of this not being a free code writing service. We're more than happy to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done so and run into difficulties, you can explain the problem you're having, include the relevant portions of your code, and ask a specific question related to that code, and we can try to help.

Comment: The reason I ask is that *in general*, the problem is mathematically impossible to solve. For instance, consider the mask `alpha_%s_beta_%s_gamma` and the output `alpha_cat_beta_beta_dog_gamma`. It is possible that the first value is `cat` and the second is `beta_dog`, but it could also be the case that the first value is `cat_beta` and the second is `dog`. So additional information must be given.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Let us exclude the repetition (we speak about more or less normal file names) and the number of %s is always 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*In general*, this problem is mathematically impossible to solve.

For instance, consider the mask `alpha_%s_beta_%s_gamma` and the output `alpha_cat_beta_beta_dog_gamma`.

It is possible that the first value is `cat` and the second is `beta_dog`, but it could also be the case that the first value is `cat_beta` and the second is `dog`. So additional information must be given.

If, for instance, you know that the mask always contains exactly one (1) instance of `%s`, then the problem is very easy to solve. For instance (omitting all error checking):

```
function GetValueFromMask(const AMask, AText: string): string;
var
  p: Integer;
begin
  p := Pos('%s', AMask);
  Result := Copy(AText, p, 2 + AText.Length - AMask.Length);
end;
```

Of course, you would *never* use that code in production. You would add error checking, making sure you handle `AText` not matching `AMask`, `AMask` containing zero or >1 `%s`, etc.

But you get the idea.

Comment: Depending on how you think about it, the correctness of the value of the third parameter to the `Copy` function is more obvious if you write it `AText.Length - (AMask.Length - 2)`.

Comment: I made some typical case test and it looks good. thanks a lot. Solution accepted.